# Lot of bandwidth consumed in Get Request to website served by Apache

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, bandwidth, website, request

Can someone help me to identify the reason for so much bandwidth consumption by our website, the webserver is Apache, and is hosted in AWS Ec2 instance along with some other websites.

In a single day our "Network out"  bandwidth utilization went to 300 GB

Below some samples from Apache access log, and attached the AWS cloud-watch graph.

---

10.20.30.40 - - [10/Sep/2019:06:50:24 +0000] "GET /events/test.php?id=1014xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 2038563160 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

10.20.30.40 - - [10/Sep/2019:06:56:09 +0000] "GET /events/test.php?id=1014xxx.9-2 HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

10.20.30.40 - - [10/Sep/2019:06:53:18 +0000] "GET /events/test.php?id=1014xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 1938298856 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

---

[image: Cloudwatch Graph]

Comment: The second number behind the request path in your log files is the amount of bytes that were transfered with the response. Check your php script and figure out why it sends about 2GB of data with the first and the last request from your log.

Comment: i dont want to make panic but check your files for some unusually content

Comment: @djdomi i have scanned the website file using clamav scanner, but not able to find anything. I have blocked bad bots from hitting the server, and used Apache mod_ratelimit module to limit the bandwidth usage, so now the utilization is reduced. Any other method to identify the rootcause?.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, iam not able to move to the next step in the troubleshooting, should i check this php file (/events/agenda.php), do you think some issue with this file ?.

Comment: do you know what this file do? you csn try to use tcpdump, or lsof to see what file are beeing read

Comment: @djdomi, ok i will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the reason for high bandwidth utilization in that particular page. Used wget http://example.com/events/test.php?id=1014xxx, downloaded the file, and identified a loop in the PHP code. After removing the loop, the page working fine now without generating lot of bandwidth.